# Add a Geoserver Layers Group into a map created with mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, geoserver

I need to add a Layers Group created in Geoserver (including several circle and line data sources)

I have just added into my map, pbf sources from Geoserver as circles and lines layers.

I have created some layersgroup on Geoserver and I'd like to add all this layer group on the map.

Would be possible to add as pbf source and reference the individual sources as layers / sub-layers into my map?

Comment: Have you tried to do this at all and run into problems? Mind sharing your debugging code? I'm not sure that this is possible right out of the box since, but I'm also not very familiar with geoserver's data structures - is there a reason you wouldn't be able to split out the layers and add them as individual sources/layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @riastrad, I have just added using a source with the Layers Group name on Geoserver and the use of the source-layer attribute in mapbox-gl-js referencing the internal layers of the Geoserver Layers Group. Thanks again!